# How to make text clickable only where the text is in android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

In my android app, I create a linear layout horizontal, and put two text views. The first text view should have layout weight of 1, so it tried to maximize its width. Also the first text view too, is click able. How can I get it so that only the text part of it is click-able?
Currently, the full width of the text view is click-able...

Thanks

```
    final LinearLayout UserLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    UserLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    UserLayout.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams taskMargin = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    UserLayout.setLayoutParams(taskMargin);
    personobj.layout = UserLayout;

    TextView name = new TextView(this);
    name.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>" + personobj.lastname + ", " + personobj.firstname + "</u>"));
    name.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.text_link);
    name.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    name.setClickable(true);
    name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (MyHTTPFunctions.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                MyInterface.RegisterForClose(ActivityEditUsers.this);

                AsyncGetProfileInfo GetProfileTask = new AsyncGetProfileInfo(ActivityEditUsers.this, personobj.ID);
                GetProfileTask.execute();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    final TextView num = new TextView(this);
    num.setText(String.format("%d", index+1));
    num.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    num.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    num.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.title_numbering);
    num.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_title_numbering);

    LinearLayout OptionLL = new LinearLayout(this);
    OptionLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    OptionLL.addView(name);
    OptionLL.addView(num);

    UserLayout.addView(OptionLL);
```

Comment: use a `SpannableString` with a clickable span http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the first TextView inside a LinearLayout. Set this LinearLayout's weight to `1`. Add TextView `name` to this LinearLayout with parameters WRAP_CONTENT and no weight. And keep the OnClickListener set on `name`:

```
LinearLayout firstTextViewHolder = new LinearLayout(this);

firstTextViewHolder.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

TextView name = new TextView(this);
name.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>" + personobj.lastname + ", " + personobj.firstname + "</u>"));
name.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.text_link);
name.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

name.setClickable(true);
name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (MyHTTPFunctions.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
            MyInterface.RegisterForClose(ActivityEditUsers.this);

            AsyncGetProfileInfo GetProfileTask = new AsyncGetProfileInfo(ActivityEditUsers.this, personobj.ID);
            GetProfileTask.execute();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});

firstTextViewHolder.addView(name);

LinearLayout OptionLL = new LinearLayout(this);
OptionLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

OptionLL.addView(firstTextViewHolder);
OptionLL.addView(num);

UserLayout.addView(OptionLL);
```